# Check if the button has been pressed after js submit

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to check if a form type button has been pressed after i submit the form with javascript:

```
<script>
function DeleteIt(string){
    var pattern = string.indexOf('_');
    var prof_nr = string.substr(pattern+1);
    var delete = confirm("Want to delete it?");

    if( delete == true ){
        document.forms['form'].submit();
    }else{
        alert('Cancel');
    }
}
</script>

<form method="POST" name="form">
<input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" id="prof_'.$row['code'].'" onclick="DeleteIt(this.id);">
</form>

if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
  echo 'Pressed';
}
```

But it doesn't run into the condition though it has been pressed.
I can't use a submit type,because i already have one in the form , which is used for a search field.Whenever i type something and hit enter,it triggers the function,that's why i use button.

Comment: Could you please add your full code to the question (including the `form`- and the `script`-tag)?

Comment: @mario.klump , there is no point showing the entire code...i believe anyone can figure out what is all about from my question.I've included the tags.

Comment: Please show the complete form. The point is some people answered without knowing why we can't use a `submit` type (or if we can and explain why).

Comment: @caCtus , i explained everything in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used so many language keywords as variable names in your code like `delete`, `string`.

> You can not use reserved words of a programming language as your
>   variable names.

This is the working code-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DeleteIt(string1){
    var pattern = string1.indexOf('_');
    var prof_nr = string1.substr(pattern+1);
    var delete1 = confirm("Want to delete it?");

    if( delete1 == true ){
        document.forms['form'].submit();
    }else{
        alert('Cancel');
    }
}
</script>

<form method="POST" name="form">
<button name="delete" id="prof_'.$row['code'].'" onclick="DeleteIt(this.id);">delete</button>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
  echo 'Pressed';
}
```

Comment: You edited your answer and replaced the `<button>` tag by a `<input type="submit">`. But OP says he doesn't want a `submit` type.

Comment: @Hirdesh , after a closer look at your code, i figured that it does the same thing as an input type..... it's not good...

Comment: i have reverted my code back to `input tag` because @petru's code include input tag only, although this thing can also be done using `button` tag.

Comment: @HirdeshVishwdewa , an submit type, interfere with the others submits i have on the same form.

Comment: @PetruLebada why do you think this isnt good to have `button` tag in place of `input`?

Comment: @caCtus i mistakenly changed `type="button"` to `type="submit"`, i edited my code, thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: @HirdeshVishwdewa , i expxlained in my question... i already have a submit in my form,if i'm using button tag or another submit type,it will interfere with this one,and it will trigger the DeleteIt function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86602/discussion-between-hirdesh-vishwdewa-and-petru-lebada).

Comment: @Hirdesh Vishwdewa, Petru Lebada does not want the button to be pressed when the enter key is hit within the form. If you add a text field right before your button tag, focus it and press enter, your button will be pressed. But this is what should be avoided here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a button, which is used to submit a form, will not submit its own value.

Since you do not want the form to be submitted by pressing the enter key, my idea is to add a hidden field which tells you what to do. The following code adds such a hidden field named *specialAction*, which is normally set to *save*. When the delete button is pressed, however, its value is changed to *delete*. In PHP, you would have to check the field's value then:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function DeleteIt(id){
                var pattern = id.indexOf('_');
                var prof_nr = id.substr(pattern+1);
                var deleteVar = confirm("Want to delete it?");

                if( deleteVar == true ){
                    document.forms['form']['specialAction'].value = "delete";
                    document.forms['form'].submit();
                }else{
                    alert('Cancel');
                }

                string 
            }
    </script>
    <form method="POST" name="form">
        <input type="hidden" id="specialAction" name="specialAction" value="save">
        <input type="text" name="testPurpose" value="Hit enter after focusing">
        <input type="button" value="Delete" name="delete" id="prof_test" onclick="DeleteIt(this.id);">
    </form>
    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['specialAction'])) echo $_POST['specialAction'];
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

A side note: Do not use `delete` as a variable name, because it is already used as an operator. Also, you should tell the browser to interpret JavaScript using `<script type="text/javascript">` and not just `<script>`.